# Combine XML Files using PHP

Tags: php, xml, merge

Trying to combine the two xml files using php and then save a new merged xml.

http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/fcdmc_alert_rain_v3.xml and http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/fcdmc_alert_return.xml

```
<FCDMC>
<rpt_info created="07-06-2017 11:24"/>
<gage_rain id="770" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="1.77" rainscore="1" name="Tat Momolikot Dam [TM]" lat=" 32.65120" long="-111.92830"/>
```

and

```
<FCDMC>
<rpt_info created="07-06-2017 11:23"/>
<return_rain id="770" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0"/>
```

Want the output to look like this

```
<FCDMC>
<rpt_info created="07-06-2017 11:24"/>
<gage_rain id="770" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="1.77" rainscore="1" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0" name="Tat Momolikot Dam [TM]" lat=" 32.65120" long="-111.92830"/>
```

I am trying to write the PHP script but it has been unsuccesful.  I am not getting any results or errors. XML is blank http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/merged.xml as is the php http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/php/merge_test.php.Here is the sript.

```
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->load('http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/fcdmc_alert_rain_v3.xml');

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->load('http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/fcdmc_alert_return.xml');

// get 'res' element of document 1
$res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('gage_rain')->item(0); //edited res - items

// iterate over 'item' elements of document 2
$items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('return_rain');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i ++) {
    $item2 = $items2->item($i);

    // import/copy item from document 2 to document 1
    $item1 = $doc1->importNode($item2, true);

    // append imported item to document 1 'res' element
    $res1->appendChild($item1);

}
$doc1->save('http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/merged.xml'); //edited -added saving into xml file
```

Anyone know what is wrong here??  I would like the php to save the desired output as a new merged xml file at location http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/merged.xml.

Comment: Could you be specific about errors and/or unexpected results?

Comment: I would like to merge the two xml files to the desired output <gage_rain id="770" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="1.77" rainscore="1" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0" name="Tat Momolikot Dam [TM]" lat=" 32.65120" long="-111.92830"/>
and have it saved to a new xml at http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/merged.xml *added to original post.

Comment: But what is the result you're getting now? Anything at all?

Comment: I am not getting any results or errors. XML is blank http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/merged.xml as is the php http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/php/merge_test.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to merge attributes from the rain nodes in both XML, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose XML transformation language. With XSLT's `document()` function, you can parse from an external saved file in a current or subdirectory relative to the xsl script.

PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts  with the [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class which is enabled as an extension in .ini file. No `for` loops or `if` logic needed for this approach.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file in same directory: alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/xml/) or embed as a PHP string)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/FCDMC">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="rpt_info"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="gage_rain"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="gage_rain">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="curr_id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('fcdmc_alert_return.xml')/FCDMC/return_rain[@id=$curr_id]/@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(load only the first XML as XSL handles the second XML)*

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$cd = dirname(__FILE__);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($cd.'/fcdmc_alert_rain_v3.xml');      

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($cd.'/XSLT_Script.xsl');           // OR $xsl->loadXML($xslstr);

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = $cd.'/merged.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FCDMC>
  <rpt_info created="07-06-2017  11:39"/>
  <gage_rain id="770" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="1.77" rainscore="1" name="Tat Momolikot Dam [TM]" lat="  32.65120" long="-111.92830" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0"/>
  <gage_rain id="775" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="1.69" rainscore="1" name="Gila R. @ Maricopa Rd. [SP]" lat="  33.17076" long="-112.00601" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0"/>
  <gage_rain id="780" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="1.22" rainscore="1" name="Gila River at Olberg [SP]" lat="  33.08706" long="-111.68700" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0"/>
  <gage_rain id="785" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="2.13" rainscore="1" name="Santa Cruz R. @ SR 84 [SP]" lat="  32.87952" long="-111.82895" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0"/>
  <gage_rain id="795" last_rpt="2017-07-06T06:00:00" min_10="0.00" min_30="0.00" hour_1="0.00" hour_3="0.00" hour_6="0.00" day_1="0.00" day_3="0.00" day_7="0.00" cytd="0.43" rainscore="1" name="Greene Wash @ SR 84 [SP]" lat="  32.87946" long="-111.93369" min10="0" min30="0" hour1="0" hour3="0" hour6="0" day1="0" day3="0" day7="0"/>
  ...
```